# Looping every value of a cell in a column until blank and for each value use all values in a different column until blank

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a task to preform and I'm half way through.
I need a loop to iterate every value on, let's say, 'A' (A1, A2, A3, etc) column and then acquire all the cell values from 'B' (B1, B2, B3, etc) column for the first cell on 'A' and them move to acquire all the values from 'C' column for the second cell on 'A' (A2), and so on.
I manage to accomplish to loop every cell on 'A' until blank and acquire all the values from 'B' until blank in 'A' column, but not to change to 'C' column when the cell on 'A' change to the second (A2).

```
Dim BlankFound As Boolean
Dim BlankFound_1 As Boolean
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long

Do While BlankFound = False
    x = x + 1
    If Worksheets("shee1").Cells(x, "A").Value = "" Then
        BlankFound = True
    ElseIf Worksheets("shee1").Cells(x, "A").Value = "title" Then

    Else
        value_1 = Worksheets("shee1").Cells(x, "A").Value
        BlankFound_1 = False
        y = 0
        Do While BlankFound_1 = False
            y = y + 1

            If Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(y, "A").Value = "" Then
                BlankFound_1 = True
            ElseIf Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(y, "A").Value = "values" Then

            Else
                value_2 = Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(y, "A").Value
            End If
       Loop
    End If

    'End If 'this End If doesn't have an If
Loop
```

Comment: I advise you to use a `For each` loop. That way you can make use of range objects in the loop, and it is also considerably faster

Comment: Please format your code better, and the use of `Then Else:` twice looks rather odd to me...

Comment: There is an extra unnecessary `End If` statement before the `Loop` statement

Comment: Hello Ken Y-N, the use of the 'Then' (and then nothing) it's because i need to eliminate the first cell in the column, in case it's the title. So in first case I want to eliminate the 'title' and in the second one 'values'. Sorry for not explaining that.

Comment: @Martin your goal is to fill column A with the sum of the columns B,C,D... how many columns are there to sum? A2 = sum column B, A3 = sum columnB, A4 = sum column D, is that right?

Comment: Hello Damian, there is no limit, can be 10 or it can be 200 but for each one in column 'A' as to the a correspondent in column 'B', 'C', 'D', etc...

Comment: Hello Tim, Yes, sorry it was my mistake please disregard extra 'End If'.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your intentions I think this will do:

```
Option Explicit
Sub consolidate()

    Dim x As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Col As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet") 'Change MySheet for your working sheet name
        Col = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'calculate the last column
        'instead looping for every cell, just use the Sum function for the range in every column
        For i = 2 To Col
            .Cells(i, 1) = Application.Sum(.Columns(i)) 'the i will increase both the column to calculate and the row for the output
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Damian, I understand what You did, but if I want to retrieve both cell value column A and correspondent cell value in the other column for each 'i' it does not work.

Comment: @Martin You want to sum the value currently in A2 + the sum of column B? and so on...

Comment: Not sum, just retrieve. For each iteration retrieve the value of the cell in 'A' column and the correspondent value or values in other column.

Comment: I don't get this.... where do you want  to put the values, how you want to separate them?? can a column have 10 values??

Comment: For example:

First Iteration (Column 'A' first cell value - 'A' correspondent column 'B' cell values "123" for the first cell,  "24" second cell , "45" third cell)
Second Iteration(Column 'A' first cell value - 'B' correspondent column 'C' cell value "1" )

Comment: @Martin I'm sorry but this is hard to understand, can you please post 2 screens? the sheet and the desired output? post it on your question please.

Comment: So I want to retrieve the values for the first iteration ["A", "123", "24", "45"] - second iteration ["B", "1"] and so on...

Comment: sorry I was in a meeting and could not reply sooner.
So adapting Your code I could go a little bit further and increment a column for each iteration however I can only retrieve one value from the following columns, ["B", "C", "D", etc] and need to retrieve all the values in each cell for each of this columns until blank.

Comment: @Martin can you please add to your question a screen for the original data, and another one with the desired output please?